# Get BlogPost based on Taxonomy

Tags: sitefinity

I'm trying to create a custom Blog post rotator for a homepage.  It shows the 5 newest posts (Title, summary, date, and link) this works with the following code

```
var posts = App.WorkWith().BlogPosts().Publihed().Get().OrderByDescending(p => p.PublicationDate).Take(5)ToList();
```

But I only want to get posts with specific Tags.  I'm able to get the Guid associated with a specific tag

```
TaxonomyManager taxmanager = TaxonomyManager.GetManager();
var taxonGuidId = taxmanager.GetTaxa<FlatTaxon>().Where(t => t.Name == "SpecificTag").Single().Id;
```

I can foreach through every post and see lots of information but cannot figure out how to determine if the specific Guid is attached to that post.  Or take the post and get a list of Taxon; something like

```
var postTaxon = GetTaxon(BlogPost)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a reason you need to use a custom widget? I would recommend using the standard list widget for blogs select the tag you want to show and then limit it to 5. Once you do that you can then us your JavaScript to create the rotator from the default classes or modify the template to have custom classes.